# How to insert and resize an image in Word?

Tags: image, vbscript, ms-word

I have written a VBScript to automate the creation of a Word document.

I'm using the following code to insert an image, but I can't seem to find a way to then resize it.

```
objSelection.InlineShapes.AddPicture("C:\test.jpg")
```

Answer (score 6):

The [`AddPicture`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.inlineshapes.addpicture%28v=office.11%29.aspx) method returns a handle to the inserted object, so you could do something like this:

```
Set pic = objSelection.InlineShapes.AddPicture("C:\test.jpg")
pic.Height = 100
pic.Width  = 200
```